# finite $\mathbb Z$ modules are also finitely generated $\mathbb Z$ algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb Z\subset A$ be integral domains.I want to prove that if $A$ is a finite $\mathbb Z$ module,then $A$ is isomorphic to the subring $\mathbb Z[\alpha_1,\alpha_2,.....,\alpha_n]$ of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ for some $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,.....,\alpha_n\in\overline{\mathbb Q}$. ($ \overline{\mathbb Q}$ denotes the ring of algebraic integers.)

For example,I was looking at $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)\simeq \mathbb Z[i]$ where $i\in \overline{\mathbb Q}$.

Now,is it true that any domain which is finitely generated as a $\mathbb Z$ module is isomorphic to the quotient of $\mathbb Z[x_1,x_2,....,x_n]$ modulo some prime ideal $I$?Then $I$ is finitely generated by polynomials say,$f_1,f_2,...,f_r$ and we can somehow attach the roots of $f_i's$ to cook up $\alpha_i's$.

Can I proceed  this way or is there any other way to prove this?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your actual difficulties are. If $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ generate $A$ as a $\Bbb Z$-module, then the map $\Bbb Z[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to A$ by $x_i\mapsto \alpha_i$ is surjective and the kernel is a prime ideal since $A$ is a domain, showing that $A\cong \Bbb Z[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/I$ for a prime ideal $I$.

Comment: @KReiser Sorry,I could not observe that.Can you please tell me one more thing? how do I get those $\alpha_i's$?

Comment: I'm asking you to clarify your question. Right now it reads to me as "if $A$ is finitely generated as a module, is it also finitely generated as an algebra?", which should be fairly clear (and is addressed by my previous comment). If that's not what you're asking, could you please edit your post to make it clearer?

Comment: @KReiser  Yeah,but how can I get those elements from $\overline{\mathbb Q}$?